# Optimising eigenvalue matrix calculation

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, eigenvalues, numerical-value

I'm quite new to mathematica and am trying to figure out how to optimise my code as currently it takes a very long time to compile and makes it hard to bug test. The first part that creates the graph of the eigenvalues against k is relatively fast, but the second part takes a large chunk of time so i'm wondering what i should change about this. Any help/advice would be really appreciated.

```
t4 = 0.3
phi = Pi/2

haldzigzaghamiltonian[n_, k_, delta_] := Table[
   If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && v == (u + 1), -2*Cos[k/2],
        If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && v == (u - 1), -2*Cos[k/2],
        If[Mod[u + v - 1, 4] == 0 && Abs[u - v] < 2, -1,
      If[
       Mod[u, 2] != 0 && (v == (u + 2) || v == (u - 2)), -t4*2*
        Cos[phi + k/2],
       If[
        Mod[u, 2] == 0 && (v == (u + 2) || v == (u - 2)), -t4*2*
         Cos[k/2 - phi], 
        If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && u == v, -t4*2*Cos[phi + k] + delta, 
         If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && u == v, -t4*2*Cos[k + phi] - delta, 
          0]]]]]]],
   {u, 2*n}, {v, 2*n}];

vx[n_, k_] := Table[If[u == v, -t4*Sin[k + phi],
        If[(u + v > 3) && (Abs[u - v] == 2), -t4*Sin[k/2 - phi],
         If[(Mod[v, 2] == 0) && Abs[u - v] == 1, -Sin[k/2], 0]]],
   {u, 2*n}, {v, 2*n}];

oka[n_] := 
  Table[If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && v == u, 1, 0], {v, 2*n}, {u, 2*n}];
okb[n_] := 
  Table[If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && v == u, 1, 0], {v, 2*n}, {u, 2*n}];

nvalue = 3;
k = Range[0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/99];
delta = 0.3;
eigvals = 
  Table[N[
    Re[Eigenvalues[
      haldzigzaghamiltonian[nvalue, k[[i]], delta]]]], {i, 100}] ;

ListPlot[
 Table[{k[[i]], eigvals[[i]][[j]]}, {i, 0, 100}, {j, 0, 2*nvalue}]]

nvalue = 20;
kvalue = 7*Pi/9;
del = Table[
   eigvecsk = 
    Eigenvectors[{haldzigzaghamiltonian[nvalue, k[[i]], delta]}];
   eigvalsk = 
    Eigenvalues[haldzigzaghamiltonian[nvalue, k[[i]], delta]];
   f[n_] := If[eigvalsk[[n]] <= 0, 1, 0];
   e[n_, nmax_, k_] := eigvalsk[[n]];
   onm[n_, m_, nmax_] := eigvecsk[[n]]\[Conjugate] . eigvecsk[[m]];
   vxnm[n_, m_, nmax_, k_] := 
    eigvecsk[[n]]\[Conjugate] . vx[nmax, k] . eigvecsk[[m]];
   func[n_, m_, nmax_, 
     k_] := (f[n] - f[m])/(e[n, nmax, k] - e[m, nmax, k])^2*
     onm[n, m, nmax]*vxnm[m, n, nmax, k];
   N[Re[Sum[
      If[p != q, func[p, q, nvalue, k[[i]]], 0], {p, 1, 2*nvalue}, {q,
        1, 2*nvalue}]]], {i, 100}];
ListLinePlot[Table[{k[[b]], del[[b]]}, {b, 0, 100}], 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

Comment: What is the second part supposed to do? What exactly do you need to speed up?

Answer (score 2):

Being an interpreted language, *Mathematica* is *very* slow with all loop constructs such as `Table`. So one should try to use matrix constructors whose backend is alread compiled. Moreover, the return `haldzigzaghamiltonian` is a sparse matrix with only few bands. Hence we can employ a `SparseArray` which will also safe quite some memory if `n` gets larger.

```
haldzigzaghamiltonian2[n_, k_, delta_] := With[{
    diag0 = -2. t4 Cos[phi + k] - (-1.)^Range[2 n] delta,
    diag1 = 
     Riffle[ConstantArray[-2. Cos[0.5 k], n], 
      ConstantArray[-1., n - 1]],
    diag2 = 2. t4 Cos[0.5 k + (-1.)^Range[2 n - 2] phi]
    },
   SparseArray[
    {
     Band[{1, 1}] -> diag0,
     Band[{1, 2}] -> diag1,
     Band[{2, 1}] -> diag1,
     Band[{1, 3}] -> diag2,
     Band[{3, 1}] -> diag2
     },
    {2 n, 2 n}
    ]
   ];
oka2[n_] := DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Mod[Range[2 n], 2]]];
okb2[n_] := DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[1 - Mod[Range[2 n], 2]]];

nvalue = 3;
k = Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, 99];
delta = 0.3;
eigvals = Table[Sort@ Eigenvalues[haldzigzaghamiltonian2[nvalue, k[[i]], delta]], {i, 100}];
ListLinePlot[Thread[{k, #}] & /@ Transpose[eigvals]]
```

[image]

Now to the rest of your code: Having had a closer look on it, I am quite confident that a more precise and significantly faster way to get its result would be

```
del = ConstantArray[0., 100];
```

;)

The reason is that `onm[n_, m_, nmax_]` is essentially equivalent to `KroneckerDelta` because `Eigenvectors` orthonormalizes the eigenvectors for machine precision inputs. But since you evaluate `func` only if `m` and `n` are distint, `func` always returns `0.` (or something very close to it due to floating point errors).

Just for completeness, here the way I would rewrite your code:

```
vx2[n_, k_] := SparseArray[{
    Band[{1, 1}] -> -t4*Sin[k + phi],
    Band[{1, 2}] -> -Sin[k/2] Mod[Range[1, 2 n - 1], 2],
    Band[{2, 1}] -> -Sin[k/2] (1 - Mod[Range[1, 2 n - 1], 2]),
    Band[{1, 3}] -> -t4*Sin[k/2 - phi],
    Band[{3, 1}] -> -t4*Sin[k/2 - phi]
    },
   {2 n, 2 n}
   ];
id = IdentityMatrix[2 nvalue, SparseArray, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
nvalue = 20;
del = Table[
   {eigvalsk, eigvecsk} = Eigensystem[haldzigzaghamiltonian2[nvalue, k[[i]], delta]];
   fvec = 1. - UnitStep[eigvalsk];
   fdiff = (# - Transpose[#] &[ConstantArray[fvec, 2 nvalue]]);
   ediff = # - Transpose[#] &[ConstantArray[eigvalsk, 2 nvalue]];
   V = ConjugateTranspose[eigvecsk].vx[nvalue, k[[i]]].eigvecsk;
   W = ConjugateTranspose[eigvecsk].eigvecsk;
   B = fdiff (ediff + id)^-2 V W;
   Total[B, 2] - Total[Diagonal[B]]
   , {i, 100}];
```

It gets the job done in half a second.

Answer (score 2):

There are some tricks that can vastly shorten the computation time for generating `del`. However, I want to mention that `f` in your code is always `0` due to the fact that
$$\text{Eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix are mutually orthogonal.}$$

The matrix `haldzigzaghamiltonian` in your code is symmetric and real (unless you set `delta` to something else having non-zero imaginary part), making `onm` always `0` (so are `f` and the `Sum`).

--

Anyways, `vxnm` is taking up the most computation time (~99%) because it's evaluating the same `vx[nvalue, k[[i]]]` for `(2*nvalue)*(2*nvalue)` times during the `Sum`, only to generate one entity in `del`. To prevent this, define `vx0 = vx[nvalue, k[[i]]]` before the `Sum` and change `vx[nmax, k]` to `vx0` in `vxnm`:

```
del = Table[
 vx0 = vx[nvalue, k[[i]]];
 eigvecsk = Eigenvectors[{haldzigzaghamiltonian[nvalue, k[[i]], delta]}];
 eigvalsk = Eigenvalues[haldzigzaghamiltonian[nvalue, k[[i]], delta]];
 f[n_] := If[eigvalsk[[n]] <= 0, 1, 0];
 e[n_] := eigvalsk[[n]];
 onm[n_, m_] := eigvecsk[[n]]\[Conjugate].eigvecsk[[m]];
 vxnm[n_, m_, nmax_, k_] := eigvecsk[[n]]\[Conjugate].vx0.eigvecsk[[m]];
 func[n_, m_, nmax_, k_] := (f[n] - f[m])/(e[n] - e[m])^2*onm[n, m]*vxnm[m, n, nmax, k];
 Re@Sum[If[p != q, func[p, q, nvalue, k[[i]]], 0], {p, 1, 2*nvalue}, {q, 1, 2*nvalue}]
, {i, 100}] // AbsoluteTiming;
First[%]

(* 18.8918 *)
```

The following graph is a benchmark, showing that this makes it about 44 times faster, asymptotically:
[image]